# KQL - is it possible to select the scope inside a request?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I specify cluster+database+table

```
cluster("my_company_kusto.westeurope").database("events").table("CourierEvents")
| where OrderId == "C61F4D3A8B93975111EC8A629DDBCF0E"
```

but I get an error `Please select a database to execute queries`. until I select a table in the left menu and the scope appears on the top.

Is it possible to select the scope inside a request without selecting it in a left menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are using one of the tools (Kusto Explorer or the Kusto Web explorer), if so the answer is **yes**. See the [connection panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/tools/kusto-explorer#connections-panel) topic in the Kusto Explorer docs, and here is the applicable example:

```
#connect cluster('help').database('Samples')

StormEvents | count
```

Execute the first line, and it will set your context to the applicable cluster and database.

Comment: I am using Azure Data Explorer. Your command worked, the scope was set. But my script is not executed after it.

Comment: if you want to execute it in one step, simply execute your original query with **any** database selected.